# How to disable "search as you type" in Android Studio's Translations Editor

Tags: android-studio, translation

This feature is driving me crazy:

Whenever I forget to double click the cell or hit <kbd>F2</kbd> before typing my translation, the Translations Editor assumes I am actually searching for a string, and takes me to a different cell, making it a hassle to find the initial cell I was planning on editing.

[image]

Is there any way to turn this "search as you type" feature off ?

Comment: Nice and useful question. I wish I knew how too